# update tkinter window without closing it

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Let's say I have a text file which contains 10 numbers

I have written a code to select and open the file, the default window shows a pushbutton to select it and an empty combobox

I would like to fill the combobox with values from the file when it is opened but without close the window

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        ButtonSelect_File = tk.Button(self, text='Select file', command=self.displayPath)
        ButtonSelect_File.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self._File = tk.StringVar(self)
        self._File.set('')
        label_File = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self._File)
        label_File.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=[])
        self.combobox.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        
    def displayPath(self):
        self.File = askopenfilename()
        self.directory = os.path.split(self.File)[0]
        self._File.set(self.File)
        
    def readFile(self, file):
        read = open(file, "r")
        values = [i for i in read]
        ### HOW TO ADD THESE VALUES TO THE COMBOBOX ####
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Application()
    obj.mainloop()
    obj.readFile(obj.File)
```

Could someone tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Why did you wrote the code then to read after the window is closed? I don't get your problem, you seem to know enough to write that code by yourself.

Comment: my problem is the readFile function is called after the combobox is created, so I do not know to update it dynamically

Comment: Well you seem aware of the concept of a Button. Why don't you use one?

Comment: I thought it was possible to do it automatically

Comment: I fixed my problem by using postcommand in combobox

Comment: That's a great solution!

Comment: @Thingamabobs ~ is it, though? It seems like more of a hack. It's certainly not necessary.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy as long as it serves as intended by the OP and they found it by themselves it's great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code to make a clear connection between your Button, file loading, and injecting values into your Combobox. I don't personally feel like there is anything here that needs explanation, but here goes. When you click your button the `command` is called which runs the `load_values` method. In that method `askopenfilename` is invoked and that will allow you to load a file. Once the file is loaded we use list comprehension to form a list that consists of all the lines in the file. That list is then assigned to the `Combobox` via it's `values` key. Finally we store the first value in the `Combobox` via the `StringVar` that was assigned to it's `textvariable` key. We end by assuring that this is the `__main__` script, and if so, we initiate our app and invoke it's `mainloop`.

In short, it's everything that you were already doing with 4 lines added that convert the file to values, and a bunch of unrelated things removed.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        loadbtn = tk.Button(self, text='Select file', command=self.load_values)
        loadbtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self._pv = tk.StringVar(self)
        pathlbl = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self._pv)
        pathlbl.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self._cbv = tk.StringVar()
        self._cb = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=self._cbv)
        self._cb.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        
    def load_values(self):
        path = askopenfilename()
        self._pv.set(path)
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            v = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
            self._cb['values'] = v
            self._cbv.set(v[0])
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().mainloop()
```